# Add pixel to canvas

Tags: javascript, addition, pixel

I want to add new pixel to a canvas like below

```
[BluePixel][NewPixel]...<br>
[BluePixel][NewPixel]...<br> 
[BluePixel][NewPixel]...<br>
```

How can I achieve this?

And how can I change the colour of the new pixel?

I tried to find the coulour-value of a pixel using the `RGBA` of the `ImageDataArray`:

```
var bilddata = context.getImageData(10, 10, 150, 150);

for (var x=0;x<bilddata.width;x++)
{
    for (var y=0;y<bilddata.height;y++) 
    {
        var idx = (x+y*bilddata.width)*4;

        var r = 255 - bilddata.data[idx+0];
        var g = 255 - bilddata.data[idx+1];
        var b = 255 - bilddata.data[idx+2];
        var a = bilddata.data[idx+3];

        txt="r: "+ r + "\n";
        txt+="g: "+ g + "\n";
        txt+="b: "+ b + "\n";
        txt+="a: "+ a + "\n";
        alert(txt);

        bilddata.data[idx+0] = r;
        bilddata.data[idx+1] = g;
        bilddata.data[idx+2] = b;
        bilddata.data[idx+3] = a;
    }
}
```

Sry i'm not english so i couldn't find a better way to describe my problem, i hope u'll understand...

Comment: The code you have seems to be inverting the colours of the pixels that are already there...

Comment: I would advise you to use `console.log` instead of `alert` to display debug messages. That would save you a lot of window closing :). Also, you should write back the modified image to the canvas using `putImageData`. Maybe you're doing so already, but your code looks like you're not doing it.